# Why custom message from messagesource not working for request param validation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator

I am trying to throw custom message while validating request parameter

```
@Size(max = 10, message = "{custom.message}")
@RequestParam(value = "param") String param)
```

My Controller method is annotated with `@Validated` .

Here is my message source configuration

```
@Bean
  public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource =
        new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages/messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return messageSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return localValidator;
  }
```

Same annotation works(shows custom message) in DTO but when using for request paramter the message is

```
custom.message
```

Why is this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got to bug, in message properties message name had a typo. In message properties i have `custom_message` but i was using `custom.message`.